# Accessing a repo in Netbeans with git

Tags: git, netbeans, repository, branch

I created a repo in my webroot folder on my server, and I'm trying to clone it within Netbeans (through a git plugin).

I'm using CakePHP, so I added my "app/" folder as a tracked folder. When I get a directory listing, I can see a ".git" file, but inside Netbeans, if I go to Team > Git > Clone... and connect after specifying the proper git repository (which is : ssh://myip:port/home/myusername/public_html/myurl.com/.git) there are no branches for me to select.

If I am inside the myurl.com folder, and enter `git status`, I get:

```
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   app/.htaccess
# ... (cont'd)
```

Which lists everything in my app folder.

This is all new to me, so forgive me if I overlooked doing something fairly obvious. I'm reading the [Netbeans git documentation](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html), but am stuck on Step 4.

Would love to get this up and going, so I can work across multiple machines on my projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Initial commit" indicates that you created the repository but have not commited anything to it. Therefore there are no branches to clone yet.
I'd recomend reading [**Pro Git**](http://git-scm.com/book) (now added to [the official Git site](http://git-scm.com/)) or some other git tutorial. Then you'll understand better the commands that Netbeans displays.

By the way, Netbeans doesn't show all the features in git. It just makes it easier to use the regular commands.

Comment: Ah ha! Got it. Thanks for the link, I've been needing to read a good Git primer.